# Qt3D qSceneLoader error when try to load .gltf

Tags: qt, qt3d, gltf, qtwidgets

I try to load gltf by using qSceneLoader

```
auto sceneObject = new Qt3DRender::QSceneLoader();
sceneObject->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("3D/test.gltf"));
auto sceneTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform();
sceneTransform->setTranslation(QVector3D(12.0f, 7.0f, 0.0f));
auto sceneEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(this->rootEntity);
sceneEntity->addComponent(sceneObject);
sceneEntity->addComponent(sceneTransform);
```

But it gives

```
Qt3D.GLTFImport: no default scene
Qt3D.Renderer.SceneLoaders: class Qt3DCore::QEntity *__cdecl Qt3DRender::Render::LoadSceneJob::tryLoadScene(class Qt3DRender::Render::Scene *,enum Qt3DRender::QSceneLoader::Status &,const class QStringList &,const class std::function<void __cdecl(class Qt3DRender::QSceneImporter *)> &) Failed to import QUrl("file:3D/test.gltf") with errors ()
```

This doesn't crash all program but object doesn't appear.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood rightly - current version of Qt3D supports only gltf1.0 when blender, which I used for making 3d model exports only to gltf2.0. Using another formats have another issue under windows - qt 5.12.5 on this platform comes without assimp plugins(bug in the installer: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-75145), so it needs to install newer version for using such stuff.